# How to get the cartesian product of two PCollections

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm very new to using Google Cloud Dataflow. I would like to get the Cartesian product of two PCollections. For example, if I have two PCollections `(1, 2)` and `("hello", "world")`, their Cartesian product is `((1, "hello"), (1, "world"), (2, "hello"), (2, "world"))`.

Any ideas how I could do that? Also, since the Cartesian product could be large, I'm hoping the solution would lazily create the product and thus avoid huge memory consumption.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any more details on what you're trying to do? How big are each of the PCollections? There are several ways of accomplishing this, and which one is better depends on the reason you want the cartesian product and the actual PCollections involved.

Comment: The two PCollections are identical. They both contain roughly 100,000 tuples of type `(String, String)`. I'm using a dictionary of English words and got their phonetic transcription in order to generate 2-word puns, such as: "fantasti-CAL-ifornia".

Comment: For a direct cartesian solution, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41051283/377366) seems to be the best answer available for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, computing the cartesian product will be expensive. If either (or both) of the collections fit in memory, you can use [side-inputs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs) to broadcast the data to all of the workers. So for your example, you'd turn the `PCollection<String>` into a side input, and then you would have a `ParDo` that took it as the main input. For each string on the main input, you could access the side-input which had an `Iterable<String>` of all the values, and you'd output the pairs (or you could in this `DoFn` choose to output only the pairs that line up).

This will to re-iterate over the entire set of words each time -- if it fits in memory this should be fine. If it has to re-fetch the side input data every time it could be problematic.

Another approach would be to rely on shuffling and keys. Say you wanted to find words with a 3-letter overlap. You can process the dictionary and produced a `PCollection` of values keyed by the 3-letter prefixes. You can also create the similar `PCollection` keyed by 3-letter suffixes. Then you can `GroupByKey` (or `CoGroupByKey`). After that, you have for each 3-letter key, all the words with that as a prefix and that as a suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll probably go with the `GroupByKey` method!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of how to do a cartesian product.

Comment: I was actually expecting to see an actual solution