# Find cartesian product of 2 lists with Apache Beam

Tags: java, list, collections, apache-beam, cartesian-product

I have 2 `PCollection`s:

```java
PCollection<List<String>> ListA =
        pipeline.apply("getListA", ParDo.of(new getListA()))
PCollection<List<String>> ListB =
        pipeline.apply("getListB", ParDo.of(new getListB()))
```

`ListA` contains:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

`ListB` contains:

```
["A","B","C"]
```

How do I end up with a `PCollection` that contains:

```
[
 ["A","1"],["A","2"],["A","3"],
 ["B","1"],["B","2"],["B","3"],
 ["C","1"],["C","2"],["C","3"],
]
```

My search has pointed me to:

[How to do a cartesian product of two PCollections in Dataflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050477/how-to-do-a-cartesian-product-of-two-pcollections-in-dataflow)

But this is dealing with KV using coGroupby with 2 outputs.
It's possible that  coGroupby can be used to create the cartesian product  of 2 lists but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a single element in each PCollection, so you just need to join those elements, and then you can do the cartesian product yourself in a DoFn

Something like

```
Flatten.pcollections(ListA, List)
.apply(WithKeys.of(null))
.apply(GroupByKey.create())
```

After that, you'll have a PCollection with a single element, which is a KV(null, Iterable(ListA, ListB)), and you can generate the cartesian product with some for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Java 8 Stream*: [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) methods as follows.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTJbhsxDL37KwifZgpnArs3pzXgBLk1QAEfix6YMe3I0QaJk8Ao8u2ulrEzzXhBgegwiyjy8T2S2uALXhlLerN83u2EssYxbMJm1bCQ1ZebQW/PsyNU0TSwzaMUNdQSvYcHFBr@DCCsdt8zcni9GLEEFazFgp3Q61@/Ad3al@3huH4Iz9@ydQYy/MzhO8ydw62v0EdrMRwPRzCcxMfXYXlz2vW27zqPXrfxcRdd//XtBphBjY7JC9Q/nVk2NYdgi0zYrIqU2SijlIco@3V9DY6sI0@agbB@SgeBJKm4gx4QfECRxEYnWy9EpdAmFLjKZFq1izJZ7oyUVLMw2k@nh1CRQD@bTlaZQCYqu2xnJ72qOkPtIY3zFZukZlkepS40k1O0FMgEpmHbHKFniZ6LxdYzBT0bnk5tSISlPhrRN0phJAtmBRaF8/FDaE0uaeP78R2FmlGRJBznQk3KvZbjg5jnxKqNehQ64V7EO@CuJPJDKFA6PN4DTi4DdoAVuTUBv5ouZJTVgNF0MUJqkOQ5ifjvTZtzGuWok8up9EjFqod2SwH/w/1sB50tQRqAIH23FJ/YqY64caG4/ekfgeEncq/CE6AGUpa3JwbVuHvpqTuRVTreAncumYC4Cizkx6F4H4OqnYLi4@XTXnNvg7fd7i8)

```java
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
```

```java
List<List<String>> cartesianProduct = Stream.of(listA, listB)
        // represent each list element as a singleton list
        .map(list -> list.stream().map(Collections::singletonList)
                // Stream<List<list<String>>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output
        //[[1], [2], [3]]
        //[[A], [B], [C]]
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // summation of pairs of inner lists
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // combinations of inner lists
                .flatMap(inner1 -> list2.stream()
                        // merge two inner lists into one
                        .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // returns List<List<String>>, otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

```java
// final output
System.out.println(cartesianProduct);
//[[1, A], [1, B], [1, C], [2, A], [2, B], [2, C], [3, A], [3, B], [3, C]]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How can I make Cartesian product with Java 8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67137084/15675591)</sup>